# Where's the mistake in my reasoning?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Task:

> Find the cardinality of all such functions $f: P(\mathbb N) \rightarrow P(\mathbb N)$ that $f(\bigcup S) = \bigcup \lbrace f(Z) \mid Z \in S \rbrace$

The answer is: $\mathfrak c$

My approach:

> Define $R(A)$ as the set of all equivalence relations on $A$. Let's denote the set of desired function by $A$. There are at most $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ functions, so $A \le 2^{\mathfrak{c}}$. On the other hand there are $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ equivalence relations on $P(\mathbb{N})$. An equivalence relation is equivalent to the division of the set.
>   For a given relation $r$ we define
>    $$f_r : P(\mathbb{N}) \rightarrow P(\mathbb{N}): f_r(S) = \bigcup_{X \in S} [X]_r $$
>   This mapping $R(P(\mathbb N)) \rightarrow A : r \mapsto f_r$ is injective wrt to $r$. Indeed, let's take two different relations $r,s$. WLOG assume $r \not\subset s$. Then there exists such pair $X$ that $[X]_r \neq [X]_s$. WLOG assume $[X]_r \not\subset [X]_s$.So there exists some $Y \in P(\mathbb N)$ that $X r Y$ but $\neg(X s Y)$. Then $Y \in f_r(X)$ but $Y \not \in f_s(X)$, so $f_r(X) \neq f_s(X)$. Hence $f_r \neq f_s$ So the mapping is injective and set $\lvert A \rvert = 2^{\mathfrak{c}}$

Where did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition of $f_r$ doesn't even define a function $P(\mathbb{N})\to P(\mathbb{N})$.  If $S\in P(\mathbb{N})$, then each $X\in S$ is an element of $\mathbb{N}$, not an element of $P(\mathbb{N})$, so $[X]_r$ is not defined.  In any case, even if it were defined, I don't know why $[X]_r\neq [X]_s$ would imply $f_r(X)\neq f_s(X)$; two different collections of sets can have the same union.

Here's a hint towards a correct solution to the problem, if you want one:

> Use the fact that any element of $P(\mathbb{N})$ can be written as a union of singleton sets.

Comment: As I read it, $S$ is intended to be a subset of $\wp(\Bbb N)$, both in the proposed argument and in the statement of the problem.

Comment: In the problem statement $S$ is a subset of $P(\mathbb{N})$, but if you take it to be a subset of $P(\mathbb{N})$ in the definition of $f_r$, then $f_r$ is a function $P(P(\mathbb{N}))\to P(\mathbb{N})$, not a function $P(\mathbb{N})\to P(\mathbb{N})$.

Comment: Eh, you’re right. It should be $f_r\left(\bigcup S\right)$, but that has other obvious problems.

Comment: Clarified a little the opening post. Can you take a look again?

Comment: @marmistrz: It still has the same problem: what does $[X]_r$ mean?  If $S\in P(\mathbb{N})$ and $X\in S$, then $X$ is an element of $\mathbb{N}$, not $P(\mathbb{N})$.